# Pass each array key as argument to an object method

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array and I want to pass each key as argument to a class method, for example:

`$arr = ['foo' => 'test', 'bar' => 'tested'];`
`$this->method($foo, $bar);`
But the number of variables passed can be different depending on each case.
I found some similar questions but none of them were what I needed.
So, how can I do this?

I want to make each key of the array becomes a variable and pass it as argument
`$arr = ['foo' => 'bar']; >>> $foo = 'bar' and then $this->method($foo)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use Vitr's simpler and more readable answer, or if you must be explicit you can use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

```
call_user_func_array(array($this, 'method'), $arr);
```

Comment: That's was exactly what i'm looking for. Thank you (: